# Запись параметров в exe файл без перекомпиляции

Tags: delphi

Есть 2 exe файла: Application.exe и Generator.exe
Application.exe - приложение, которое в дальнейшем будет кому-либо отправлено
Generator.exe - приложение, которое должно вносить изменения в Application.exe, а именно изменять текст в Memo и Edit.
Какие варианты реализации данной идеи существуют?

Comment: Если exe не запакован и исходный текст этих Edit и Memo расположен не в константах в коде (pas), а в dfm - то Вам поможет правка ресурсов.

Comment: Перекомпиляция из коммандной строки не настолько долгий процесс, кстати, зато можете подменять все что угодно и на что угодно.